# MSSQL stored procedure select all columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure where the SELECT statement looks like this:

```
SELECT @KeyName FROM dbo.FiConfig WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE IssuerKey = @IssuerKey
```

Where I'm creating it like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GET_FICONFIG
   @IssuerKey INT,
   @KeyName NVARCHAR(100)
```

Where `KeyName` is the column name I am retrieving my data from.

My question: is it possible to pass in `*` to select all columns although the procedure is asking for a specific column name?

Edit: 
Unfortunately I think I may have worded my question poorly. I was looking for a way to see if my stored procedure could tell if I wanted to select all records from the table, or just specific columns from a record. I've solved my own problem using some NULL checks and if/else statements.

Comment: the sp might be "asking" for a specific column name, but the result of your `SELECT` will actually be the column **name**, not the values of the column

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, that's the behavior I'm expecting. I'm fairly new to SQL!

Comment: Any particular query will always return result sets with a fixed "shape" - the number, names and types of columns in the result set. If you want to change which column(s) are produced, then you need to be constructing new queries at runtime - also known as dynamic SQL.

Comment: @T.S. As it is, no, it's not prone to SQL injection. What op actually wants to do (use dynamic SQL) could be

Comment: @Lamak So, if someone puts another select into `@KeyName`, it will not work?

Comment: @T.S. If you give the value `'SELECT'` to the `@KeyName` variable, then the query will translate to `SELECT 'SELECT' FROM dbo.FiConfig.....`, which will return `'SELECT'` for every row that matches the criteria of the `WHERE` condition

Comment: @Lamak Ah, you right. It really inserts the value not the SQL

Comment: Since you say you are new to sql why are you using that NOLOCK hint? Are you aware of the implications of using that hint? It can and will return duplicate and/or missing rows. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: @SeanLange My department head told me to. I've seen it in others' stored procs also from my company, so I'm just doing what I'm told.

Comment: You might want to read up on just how truly god awful littering your database is with that hint and then have a discussion with your department head. So many people think it is a magic "go faster" button and the only side effect is dirty reads. It is so much worse than that. Even if you are met with resistance please take note for yourself so that when you work elsewhere you understand the evils that hints brings to the table.

Comment: @SeanLange I was told it would prevent locking others from using the database records while someone else is modifying them. Is that not the case?

Comment: Read the article I posted. It will allow you to read a row that somebody else is modifying. This is a dirty read. It is however minor in comparison to rows that go missing or are duplicated. In a financial application it is negligent and borderline criminal. I experienced first hand how bad that hint can be in a financial application. It cost the company hundreds of thousands of dollars if not millions because the lead dba demanded that every single query use that hint. I urge you to read that article and understand the significance.

Comment: Here are three of my other favorite articles on this topic. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidlean/archive/2009/04/06/sql-server-nolock-hint-other-poor-ideas.aspx http://www.jasonstrate.com/2012/06/the-side-effect-of-nolock/ http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/tonyrogerson/archive/2006/11/10/1280.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dynamic query:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GET_FICONFIG
   @IssuerKey INT,
   @KeyName NVARCHAR(100)
AS
declare @s varchar(500) = 'SELECT ' + @KeyName + ' FROM dbo.FiConfig WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE IssuerKey = ' + CAST(@IssuerKey as VARCHAR(10))
exec(@s)
```

You should be careful here. Possible `Sql Injection`. But you can not pass column names as parameters to dynamic query, so there is no other way.

But you can select from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` table to be sure that valid column name passed:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
          WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'FiConfig' AND COLUMN_NAME = @KeyName)
BEGIN
    declare @s varchar(500) = 'SELECT ' + @KeyName + ' FROM dbo.FiConfig WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE IssuerKey = ' + CAST(@IssuerKey as VARCHAR(10))
    exec(@s)
END
ELSE
    THROW...
```

**EDIT:**

As user @Lamak said better use `QUOTENAME` function. it will automatically add brackets around the value of variable:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GET_FICONFIG
   @IssuerKey INT,
   @KeyName NVARCHAR(100)
AS
declare @s varchar(500) = 'SELECT ' + QUOTENAME(@KeyName) + ' FROM dbo.FiConfig WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE IssuerKey = ' + CAST(@IssuerKey as VARCHAR(10))
exec(@s)
```

Comment: You should use `QUOTENAME` on `@KeyName` to avoid issued with some column names. Also, it would be better if you explicitely cast `@IssuerKey` as varchar

Comment: I'd also recommend checking for `TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'` in the query on `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
DECLARE @SqlCommand nvarchar(max)

SELECT @SqlCommand = 'SELECT ' + @keyname + ' FROM dbo.FiConfig WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE IssuerKey = ' + cast(@IssuerKey as varchar(10))

EXEC sp_executeSQL @SqlCommand
```

This would allow you to pass in either a column name or arbitrary expression (such as `*` or an aggregate function like `sum()`)

Bear in mind that as it stands, this is dangerous, as there is no validation on @keyname, so it is prone to SQL injection if someone passes in, for instance the string `''; DELETE FROM USERS; --`.

You can, however, parameterise `sp_executesql` to mitigate this; the documentation for this stored procedure is here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188001.aspx

Parameterisation of `sp_executesql` would, however, prevent you from passing in `'*'` as your argument to the stored procedure...